# Creating Objective-C Structs using ctypes?

Tags: python, macos, ctypes

I'm attempting to create the `CGRect` Struct from Apple's CoreGraphics library using Python ctypes.

Inside of `CoreGraphics/CGBase.h` `CGRect` is defined as following:

```
/* Points. */

struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;

/* Sizes. */

struct CGSize {
  CGFloat width;
  CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;

/* Rectangles. */

struct CGRect {
  CGPoint origin;
  CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

In python, I've tried to recreate the Struct with this code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

cg = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library('CoreGraphics'))

class CGPoint(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ctypes.c_float),
        ('y', ctypes.c_float)
    ]

class CGSize(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('width', ctypes.c_float),
        ('height', ctypes.c_float)
    ]

class CGRect(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('origin', CGPoint),
        ('size', CGSize)
    ]
```

This appears to work. I can inspect it and assign values to it with no problem.

```
myCoolRect = CGRect()
myCoolRect.origin.x = 0.0
myCoolRect.origin.y = 0.0
myCoolRect.size.width = 1000.0
myCoolRect.size.height = 1000.0
```

However, if I try to pass this struct to a function from `ApplicationServices`, for instance, `CG.CGWindowListCreateImage()`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: depythonifying struct, got no sequence
```

Did I set up the Struct incorrectly..?

Comment: I tracked that error string down to [PyObjC](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc). I don't know much about it, but [the docs say](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/core/typemapping.html) that you're supposed to use a `tuple` or a mutable "framework wrapper" to represent a struct. How does ctypes fit in here?

Answer (score 1):

If you open `CGBase.h` you will find:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

So `CGFLOAT` can either be a float or a double depending if you are running 32 bit or 64 bit. You are using float. Perhaps you are on 64 bit but using `float` instead of `double`?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use tuples in pyObjc, simply (123,456) instead of struct.pack('QQ',123,456)